# image issue on android

Tags: android

I have downloaded the image from given url,and displayed in the imageview,which works fine in the emulator .but not works in real device... whats the problem?

Here my code

```
final String url = urlStr;
            InputStream inputStream = null;

            try {
                inputStream = httpRequest.openHttpConnection(url);
                if(inputStream!=null)
                {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
               if(bitmap!=null)
                {
                width=bitmap.getWidth();
                height=bitmap.getHeight();
                int newWidth = 50;
                int newHeight = 50;
             // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
                float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
                float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
                // create matrix for the manipulation
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                // resize the bit map
                matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
               // recreate the new Bitmap
               resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,width, height, matrix, true);
                }
               inputStream.close();
            } 
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return  resizedBitmap;
```

Comment: Before I go to the trouble of fixing up code that can't be trivially pasted into an empty app, what does "not works" mean? Force close? Missing picture? Picture appears at wrong size? (Re that last one what do you want to do with resizedBitmap?)

Comment: it throws null pointer exception.......force close

Answer (score 1):

why dont you resize it the easy way?

```
Bitmap scaledImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, intWidth, intHeight, false);
```